# Take information from multiple table

Tags: mysql, join

i need help on this. I don't know how to use join in mysql so I try this to avoid to use join.

I have to have in the end this type of table:
tracce.titolo - data - aka (where tracce.idma=artist.id) - aka (for featuring. so i need to achive ida, that's id that identify the featured artist, and i do this under this condition feat.idt=tracce.id (so where the id from the track is the same for the id of the track in the feat table) and where artist.id=feat.ida (so where the id that identify the artist in feat table is the same of the one in the table of artists)).

I try this but it not work, that's the code:

```
SELECT tracce.titolo, tracce.data, artist.aka, feat.ida FROM tracce, artist, feat
WHERE tracce.idma=artist.id AND feat.idt=tracce.id
SELECT artist.aka FROM tracce
WHERE artist.id=feat.ida
```

Table structure is:
`artist: id - aka`
`tracce: id - titolo - idma - data (id of track, titolo is title of the track, idma is the id of the main artist and data is date)`
`feat: idt - ida (idt is the id of the track and ida is the id of the featured artist)`

EDIT: modify the code made by Christian, I solve adding another join on artist table using two different alias and it seems to work.

```
SELECT tracce.titolo, tracce.data, a1.aka as 'main', a2.aka as 'feat' from tracce 
  JOIN artist a1
    ON tracce.idma = a1.id
  JOIN feat 
    ON feat.idt = tracce.id
  JOIN artist a2
    ON a2.id = feat.ida
```

Comment: Sounds like you are just having issues with `join` and `mysql`, not PHP. If you are having issues with PHP you should add the code. Could be that the driver/function you are using is only for 1 query. You should use a `join`, with `join` syntax and `on` relation functionality.

Comment: I also can't really follow the table structures defined in the paragraph. Can you please add table schemas?

Comment: Can you please provide how you tables are structured and What are you expecting from your Sql query so that we can Help you

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: Please don't insert EDITs/UPDATEs, just make your post the best presentation as of editing time. Please don't edit a question to give an answer, post an answer. This can be expected to be a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you had in the first statement is an implicit join - not recommended as it will become obsolete.  Not exactly sure if I understood, but perhaps this is what you're looking for?

```
SELECT tracce.titolo, tracce.data, artist.aka, feat.ida from tracce 
  JOIN artist 
    ON tracce.idma = artist.id
  JOIN feat 
    ON feat.idt = tracce.id AND artist.id = feat.ida
```

I am using table aliases to make code shorter.

Comment: it says: #1054 - Unknown column 'a.ida' in 'on clause', i tryed it on phpmyadmin

Comment: Thanks Mbula Mboma Jean gilbert for the edit.  Code edited to remove table aliases.  Also, it should probably be a.id or artist.id instead of a.ida.  Misread/mistyped from your post.  From here, you can expand on it -- like adding AND and OR statements as needed.  Just make sure that if you want to AND the tables, it would have already been joined first.

Comment: So, it doesn't work becouse it doesn't return anything. If i delete "AND artist.id = feat.ida" it works but it return the ID of the featured artist and I want the aka connected to that id. It seems like it need another join to artist table but it return error infact i did: "SELECT tracce.titolo, tracce.data, artist.aka from tracce 
  JOIN artist 
    ON tracce.idma = artist.id
  JOIN feat 
    ON feat.idt = tracce.id
  JOIN artist 
    ON artist.id = feat.ida" and it says " #1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'artist' "

Comment: Andrea Riccio - what's there is how you can join three tables using INNER JOINs. If the "AND" clauses doesn't work, then there are other ways.  Try joining them all together without the AND clauses, but you can also use the WHERE clauses right after each JOIN statement to filter what you need.  Do you get what I mean?